# Getting started with Wt (Witty) in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wt

I have installed Wt-3.3.5-rc2-msvs2013-Windows-x86-SDK with installer from http://sourceforge.net/projects/witty/files/wt/3.3.5/ and I'm trying to build the first solution from here http://andres.jaimes.net/780/how-to-create-a-first-application-using-wt-witty/ and have done the points from "In order to successfully compile any of these applications you have to let your compiler know about the additional include and lib folders and files." But still I get this kind of errors, any idea, why?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hello, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\http\request(83): warning C4251: 'Wt::Http::UploadedFile::fileInfo_' : class 'boost::shared_ptr<Wt::Http::UploadedFile::Impl>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::Http::UploadedFile'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\http\request(414): warning C4251: 'Wt::Http::Request::cookies_' : class 'std::map<std::string,std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::Http::Request'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(242): warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'boost::signals2::trackable' used as base for dll-interface class 'Wt::WObject'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\boost\signals2\trackable.hpp(38) : see declaration of 'boost::signals2::trackable'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(241) : see declaration of 'Wt::WObject'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(516): warning C4251: 'Wt::WObject::statelessSlots_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WStatelessSlot *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WObject'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WStatelessSlot *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(520): warning C4251: 'Wt::WObject::name_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WObject'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(531): warning C4251: 'Wt::WObject::emptyObjectList_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WObject *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WObject'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WObject *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wobject(540): warning C4251: 'Wt::WObject::trackable_ptr_' : class 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WObject'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wstring(532): warning C4251: 'Wt::WString::utf8_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WString'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wstring(546): warning C4251: 'Wt::WString::stArguments_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WString,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WString'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WString
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wanimation(173): warning C4251: 'Wt::WAnimation::effects_' : class 'Wt::WFlags<Wt::WAnimation::AnimationEffect>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WAnimation'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wsignal(572): warning C4251: 'Wt::EventSignalBase::connections_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::EventSignalBase::StatelessConnection,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::EventSignalBase'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::EventSignalBase::StatelessConnection
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wsignal(573): warning C4251: 'Wt::EventSignalBase::flags_' : class 'std::bitset<7>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::EventSignalBase'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wsignal(580): warning C4251: 'Wt::EventSignalBase::dummy_' : class 'boost::signals2::signal<void (void),boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,int,std::less<Group>,boost::function<Signature>,boost::function<R (const boost::signals2::connection &)>,boost::signals2::mutex>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::EventSignalBase'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Group=int
1>  ,            Signature=void (void)
1>  ,            R=void
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(89): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::modifiers' : class 'Wt::WFlags<Wt::KeyboardModifier>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(92): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::touches' : class 'std::vector<Wt::Touch,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::Touch
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(92): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::targetTouches' : class 'std::vector<Wt::Touch,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::Touch
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(92): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::changedTouches' : class 'std::vector<Wt::Touch,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::Touch
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(101): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::type' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(104): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::tid' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(106): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::response' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(108): warning C4251: 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent::userEventArgs' : class 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JavaScriptEvent'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wevent(435): warning C4251: 'Wt::WDropEvent::dropMimeType_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WDropEvent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wexception(42): warning C4251: 'Wt::WException::what_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WException'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wstringstream(210): warning C4251: 'Wt::WStringStream::bufs_' : class 'std::vector<std::pair<char *,int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WStringStream'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::pair<char *,int>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlogger(227): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLogger::fields_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WLogger::Field,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLogger'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WLogger::Field
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlogger(235): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLogger::rules_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WLogger::Rule,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLogger'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WLogger::Rule
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wjavascript(387): warning C4251: 'Wt::JSignal<Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>::name_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JSignal<Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wjavascript(387): warning C4251: 'Wt::JSignal<Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>::senderId_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::JSignal<Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwidget(1236): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWidget::flags_' : class 'std::bitset<6>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwidget(1238): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWidget::eventSignals_' : class 'std::list<Wt::EventSignalBase *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWidget'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::EventSignalBase *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwebwidget(387): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWebWidget::elementTagName_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWebWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwebwidget(390): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWebWidget::AllChangeFlags' : class 'std::bitset<31>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWebWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwebwidget(398): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWebWidget::flags_' : class 'std::bitset<31>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWebWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wwebwidget(503): warning C4251: 'Wt::WWebWidget::emptyWidgetList_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WWidget *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WWebWidget'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WWidget *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlink(186): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLink::value_' : class 'boost::variant<std::string,Wt::WResource *,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLink'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssdecorationstyle(216): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle::cursorImage_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssdecorationstyle(222): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle::backgroundImageLocation_' : class 'Wt::WFlags<Wt::Side>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssdecorationstyle(224): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle::textDecoration_' : class 'Wt::WFlags<Wt::WCssDecorationStyle::TextDecoration>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssDecorationStyle'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(78): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssRule::selector_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssRule'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(286): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::media_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(288): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::rules_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WCssRule *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WCssRule *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(289): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::rulesAdded_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WCssRule *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WCssRule *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(291): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::rulesModified_' : class 'std::set<Wt::WCssRule *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=Wt::WCssRule *
1>  ,            _Ty=Wt::WCssRule *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(292): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::rulesRemoved_' : class 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcssstylesheet(294): warning C4251: 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet::defined_' : class 'std::set<std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WCssStyleSheet'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlocale(233): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLocale::name_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLocale'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlocale(234): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLocale::decimalPoint_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLocale'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlocale(234): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLocale::groupSeparator_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLocale'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wlocale(237): warning C4251: 'Wt::WLocale::time_zone_' : class 'boost::shared_ptr<tz_type>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WLocale'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              tz_type=boost::date_time::time_zone_base<boost::posix_time::ptime,char>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wmessageresourcebundle(171): warning C4251: 'Wt::WMessageResourceBundle::messageResources_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WMessageResources *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WMessageResourceBundle'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WMessageResources *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2161): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::requestTooLarge_' : class 'Wt::Signal<int64_t,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2203): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::weakSession_' : class 'boost::weak_ptr<Wt::WebSession>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2215): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::renderedInternalPath_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2215): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::newInternalPath_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2216): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::internalPathChanged_' : class 'Wt::Signal<std::string,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2216): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::internalPathInvalid_' : class 'Wt::Signal<std::string,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass,Wt::NoClass>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2224): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::javaScriptClass_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2234): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::htmlClass_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2234): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::bodyClass_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2240): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::focusId_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2244): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::scriptLibraries_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WApplication::ScriptLibrary,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WApplication::ScriptLibrary
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2248): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::styleSheets_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WCssStyleSheet,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WCssStyleSheet
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2249): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::styleSheetsToRemove_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WCssStyleSheet,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WCssStyleSheet
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2253): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::metaHeaders_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::MetaHeader,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::MetaHeader
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2254): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::metaLinks_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WApplication::MetaLink,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WApplication::MetaLink
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2256): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::exposedSignals_' : class 'std::map<std::string,Wt::EventSignalBase *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=Wt::EventSignalBase *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2257): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::exposedResources_' : class 'std::map<std::string,Wt::WResource *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=Wt::WResource *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2258): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::encodedObjects_' : class 'std::map<std::string,Wt::WObject *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=Wt::WObject *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2260): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::justRemovedSignals_' : class 'std::set<std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2265): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::afterLoadJavaScript_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2265): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::beforeLoadJavaScript_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2267): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::autoJavaScript_' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2271): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::javaScriptPreamble_' : class 'std::vector<Wt::WJavaScriptPreamble,std::allocator<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Wt::WJavaScriptPreamble
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2276): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::javaScriptLoaded_' : class 'std::set<const char *,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2279): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::showLoadingIndicator_' : class 'Wt::EventSignal<Wt::NoClass>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2279): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::hideLoadingIndicator_' : class 'Wt::EventSignal<Wt::NoClass>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wapplication(2282): warning C4251: 'Wt::WApplication::objectStore_' : class 'std::map<const char *,boost::any,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WApplication'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *
1>  ,            _Ty=boost::any
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcontainerwidget(367): warning C4251: 'Wt::WContainerWidget::flags_' : class 'std::bitset<8>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WContainerWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wcontainerwidget(368): warning C4251: 'Wt::WContainerWidget::contentAlignment_' : class 'Wt::WFlags<Wt::AlignmentFlag>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WContainerWidget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wtext(268): warning C4251: 'Wt::WText::text_' : struct 'Wt::WText::RichText' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WText'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wtext(256) : see declaration of 'Wt::WText::RichText'
1>c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\wt\wtext(280): warning C4251: 'Wt::WText::flags_' : class 'std::bitset<9>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Wt::WText'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory(348): error C4996: 'std::_Uninitialized_copy0': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory(333) : see declaration of 'std::_Uninitialized_copy0'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\boost\signals2\detail\auto_buffer.hpp(191) : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::uninitialized_copy<I,boost::shared_ptr<void>*>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=boost::shared_ptr<void> *
1>  ,            I=boost::shared_ptr<void> *
1>  ,            _InIt=boost::shared_ptr<void> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\wt 3.3.5 msvs2013 x86\include\boost\signals2\detail\auto_buffer.hpp(178) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::detail::auto_buffer<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::store_n_objects<10>,boost::signals2::detail::default_grow_policy,std::allocator<T>>::copy_rai<I,false>(I,I,boost::shared_ptr<void> *,const boost::integral_constant<bool,false> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::shared_ptr<void>
1>  ,            I=boost::shared_ptr<void> *
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

You have to make a distinction between errors and warnings. At the moment I only read one error in your log.

So, because one can not compile as long there is a least one error, we have to look at it. Also you have a ton of warnings, but as all warnings, they won't prevent compiling. But as any warning, you should be aware of them.

### About the warnings

I get these warnings too, but since it seems that they are generated by a not 100% compliant use of the DLL API by Wt, windows way of shared linking. So IMHO they can be ignored, without much to worry.

### About the one error

The one error you got, is basically a warning, because Microsoft likes to assume, that you're a dump developer and complains that using a function in C++, **could** be unsafe (called SDL). But since almost everything in the whole C++ language is "unsafe", C++ heavily relies on you to be a reasonable developer. (One could put more opinion in here about this :-)).
That's the reason why I think you can ignore this warning, also because it's Wts "fault".

### Solution

You have to options to deal with it

1. Degrade that one type of "error" to a warning by either define the preprocessor macro `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, probably in the project settings.
2. [Disable all SDL checks, so you won't be bothered by errors and warnings, which are most the time, not indicating wrong language usage.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) (I recommend this, unless you like Visual Basic and think windows is the best OS, but then I would also recommend to not use C++ :-) )